# Where can I set the fee value for accepting transactions?

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees, mining-reward

If I run a miner where can I set the fee value to accept transactions in the bitcoin client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the transactions are chosen by the client you issue your `getwork` requests to. If you're mining in a pool, the pool chooses the transactions.

The key settings are in the `main.h` file. Look at `MIN_TX_FEE` and `MIN_RELAY_TX_FEE`.

To accept non-standard transactions, comment out these lines in `main.cpp`:

```
// Rather not work on nonstandard transactions (unless -testnet)
if (!fTestNet && !IsStandard())
    return error("AcceptToMemoryPool() : nonstandard transaction type")
```

Note that if you accept transactions with less than the normal transaction fees, you should connect to [Luke Dash Jr.'s node](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Free_transaction_relay_policy) to make sure you get such transactions, since most clients won't relay them to you. Add `-addnode=173.242.112.53` to the command line you use to start your client.